# Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs with firebase and svelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to fetch simple data from firebase using svelteKit, but I get this error:

Data returned from `load` while rendering / is not serializable: Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs (data.days_status.days_data[0].date)

+page.server.js

```
.
.
export async function load() {  
    let days_data = [];  
    const querySnapshot = await dailyStatusCollection.get();        
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        days_data.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
    })  
    return {days_status:  {days_data} }
}
```

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    /**
    * @type {{ days_status: any[]; }}
    */
    export let data

</script>

{#each data.days_status as d}
    {d.status} 
{/each}
```

Anyone can help me with this issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
export async function load() {  
    const querySnapshot = await dailyStatusCollection.get(); 
    return {
            days_status: querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
                    {...doc.data(), id: doc.id} ))
            };
}
```

For the +page.svelte

```
<script>
    /**
    * @type {{ days_status: any[]; }}
    */
    export let data

</script>


{#each data.days_status as d }
    {d.id} 
    {d.status} 
{/each}
```